# Probability in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^{r}\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, congruences

My question may be not interesting or easy to answer ! but I am really not familiar with proba.
Let $p$ be an odd prime number. and let $r\geq1$ an integer. choose an element $A\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^{r+1}\mathbb{Z})$
What is the probability for which $Tr(A)\equiv p^{r}\pmod{p^{r+1}}$ and 
$Tr(A)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p^{r+1}}$ ?

Comment: Not really a probability question: it's counting solutions for some Diophantine equations mod $q$. Also $F_q$ (or  ${\bf F}_q$) usually denotes a finite field of $q$ elements, which is not the same as the integers mod $q$ once $q=p^e$ with $e>1$.

Comment: Do you want to know exact or approximate probabilities? The latter is quite easy, the former not so much.

Comment: @IgorRivin both if possible

Comment: I removed the tags "probability" and "probabilistic number theory" and "group theory" and "finite groups", because your question did not belong to these subjects (even though it is formulated in terms of matrices, probability, and congruences). I added the tag "number theory" though, because your question is purely number theoretic.

Comment: @GHfromMO These tags make sense because the question is of interest if you're interested in any of these subjects (finite groups, enumerative combinatorics). Recall that the tag XXX means that people subscribing to XXX will have the question emphasized, not that the question is a hot topic research primarily belonging on XXX. So I think removing these tags is pointless.

Comment: @YCor: I think we agree on the purpose of tags, but we seem to disagree what makes a question interesting to a certain group of people. In particular, I am certain that people who subscribe to probability are disappointed by seeing this question, because there is no genuine probability theory in it. Arguably, there is some (but not much) group theory in it. On the other hand, the number theory and the congruences tags were missing, but one can only have 5 tags, so one must be selective. One could add linear algebra as well, because, after all, $\mathrm{GL}_2$ comes from linear algebra.

Comment: @YCor: Anyways, I removed the tags in good will, not in bad will, and I apologize if I made any harm. Feel free to add any tags you like, I will not remove them.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks for your understanding :) I actually added a group tag as I'm myself interested by questions pertaining in any respect to group theory. Actually for a question on groups (such as counting), it's not always clear a priori if using the group structure will help. By the way I also often remove tags when they seem off-topic or too narrow, especially when I expect the potentially interested users to be already in the scope of another tag.

Comment: @YCor: OK, so I added the parent tag "gr.group-theory" as well!

Answer (score 10):

Total number of elements in $$\bigl|\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^{r+1}\mathbb{Z})\bigr|=p^{4r}(p^2-1)(p^2-p).$$ Let us count the number of matrices with a given trace $s$. It is $$\sum_{a\in \mathbb{Z}/p^{r+1}\mathbb{Z}} \bigl|(c,d):p\, \text{does not divide}\, a(s-a)-cd\bigr|.$$ Clearly it depends only on the remainder of $s$ modulo $p$. For $s$ divisible by $p$, we have $p^{2r}(p-1)^2$ pairs $(c,d)$ for any $a$ divisible by $p$ and $p^{2r+2}-(p^{r+1}-p^r)$ pairs for $a$ not divisible by $p$. The total number is $$p^{3r}(p-1)^2+(p^{2r+2}-(p^{r+1}-p^r))(p^{r+1}-p^r)\\=(p^{r+1}-p^r)(p^{2r}(p-1)+p^{2r+2}-p^{r+1}+p^r).$$ So, for any given remainder $s$ modulo $p^{r+1}$, which is divisible by $p$, the probability that a random matrix from $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^{r+1}\mathbb{Z})$ has a trace equal to $s$, equals $$\frac{p^{r}(p-1)+p^{r+2}-p+1}{p^{2r+1}(p^2-1)}.$$